# how to dim a variable that has both numbers and letters?

Tags: excel, vba

As I am new to Excel VBA, how to classify a variable that has both letters and numbers? Like for instance "f0rmym8" do I `Dim As Long` or `Dim As String` or something else?

Thanks!

Comment: Dim as String should work fine.

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary) you would classify this as a `string`.

Comment: @Plutian How about the case where the integers begin first? Like 8formym?

Comment: @BrianMStafford ^

Comment: See my answer. `String` is the only data tape capable of holding any kind of characters, the rest of the data types are purely numeric. This is regardless of whether it *also* has numeric characters.

Comment: @Plutian alright, thanks!

Comment: Maybe worth noting that while `000123` is a number you'll lose the leading zeros if you store it as a `Long`, but they'll stay with a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary) the string type variable is the only one capable of holding characters. (with the exclusion of variant, being able to hold an array of strings). All other data types are practically purely numeric, including `Date` and `Boolean` in VBA, with `Date` being effectively a `Double` formatted as a date, and a `Boolean` being -1 (true) or 0 (false).

In summary whenever you need to hold any kind of ASCII character that is not numeric, you will need to use the `string` data type, regardless of whether there are also numeric characters present. A numeric data type is always incapable of holding any type of text.

Answer (score 0):

A `String` can hold any group of characters, consider:

```
Sub catscradle()
    Dim Letters As String, MixedStuff As String, JustNumerals As String
    Dim NothingAtAll As String

    Letters = "ABC"
    MixedStuff = "1A2B3C"
    JustNumerals = "0076941"
    NothingAtAll = ""
End Sub
```